# Do "algorithms" exist in Functional Programming?

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming

Is it meaningless to be asked to document "algorithms" of your software (say, in a design specification) if it is implemented in a functional paradigm? Whenever I think of algorithms in technical documents I imagine a while loop with a bunch of sequential steps.

Looking at the informal dictionary meaning of an algorithm:

> In mathematics and computer science, an algorithm is a **step-by-step procedure** for calculations.

The phrase "step-by-step" appears to be against the paradigm of functional programming (as I understand it), because functional programs, in contrast to imperative programs, have no **awareness of time** in their hypothetical machine. Is this argument correct? Or does lazy evaluation enforce an implicit time component that makes it "step by step"?

*EDIT - so many good answers, it's unfair for me to choose a best response :( Thanks for all the perspectives, they all make great observations.*

Comment: Whatever language you use, operations occur in a given sequence. Indeed, in functional programming one of the challenges is realising that you may be forcing a particular sequence.

Comment: Lambda calculus was invented as an attempt to give a *formal* definition of what algorithm is. Ever since then any informal definition is meaningless.

Comment: Functional programming certainly has an awareness of time. Arguments to functions must be evaluated before the function can be *fully* evaluated. (Lazy evaluation merely delays that evaluation as long as possible, rather than forcing evaluation before the body of the function begins.)

Comment: I'd forgotten about recursion which by definition must have a sequence :)

Comment: Very well put: "Arguments to functions must be evaluated before the function can be fully evaluated"

Comment: @SK-logic Your point that lambda calculus was *invented* for algorithms is huge and gets to the crux of the matter. I don't agree that informal definitions of "algorithm" are "meaningless," though.

Comment: Not sure I see this as a valid SO question - more like [ComputerScience.se] if it would be allowed there.  This can't really have a definitive answer, as it's all interpretation of words (what is "step by step"? what is "step"?  what is "algorithm"?), so it's inevitably a discussion question rather than a Q&A question.

Comment: How a computer execute a lazy or eager functional code and if it does calculations in steps is not open for opinion. There is a consensus on it amongst the answers. How can anyone say it's opinion based? I agree with @Joe, but I think [Computer science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) is a better match.

Comment: I think my perception of "time" is the part was subjective, but the rest seems objective. I didn't realize there was a Computer Science section. I'll use that next time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, algorithms still exist in functional languages, although they don't always look the same as imperative ones.

Instead of using an implicit notion of "time" based on state to model steps, functional languages do it with **composed data transformations**. As a really nice example, you could think of heap sort in two parts: a transformation from a list into a heap and then from a heap into a list.

You can model step-by-step logic quite naturally with recursion, or, better yet, using existing higher-order functions that capture the various computations you can do. Composing these existing pieces is probably what I'd really call the "functional style": you might express your algorithm as an unfold followed by a map followed by a fold.

Laziness makes this even more interesting by blurring the lines between "data structure" and "algorithm". A lazy data structure, like a list, never has to *completely* exist in memory. This means that you can compose functions that build up large intermediate data structures without actually needing to use all that space or sacrificing asymptotic performance. As a trivial example, consider this definition of `factorial` (yes, it's a cliche, but I can't come up with anything better :/):

```
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

This has two composed parts: first, we generate a list from `1` to `n` and then we fold it by multiplying (`product`). But, thanks to laziness, the list never has to exist in memory completely! We evaluate as much of the generating function as we need at each step of `product`, and the garbage collector reclaims old cells as we're done with them. So even though this *looks* like it'll need `O(n)` memory, it actually gets away with `O(1)`. (Well, assuming numbers all take `O(1)` memory.)

In this case, the "structure" of the algorithm, the sequence of steps, is provided by the list structure. The list here is closer to a for-loop than an actual list!

So in functional programming, we can create an algorithm as a sequence of steps in a few different ways: by direct recursion, by composing transformations (maybe based on common higher-order functions) or by creating and consuming intermediate data structures lazily.

Answer (score 11):

I think you might be misunderstanding the functional programming paradigm.

Whether you use a functional language (Lisp, ML, Haskell) or an imperative/procedural one (C/Java/Python), you are specifying the operations and their order (sometimes the order might not be specified, but this is a side issue).

The functional paradigm sets certain limits on what you can do (e.g., no side effects), which makes it easier to reason about the code (and, incidentally, easier to write a "Sufficiently Smart Compiler").

Consider, e.g., a functional implementation of factorial:

```
(defun ! (n)
  (if (zerop n)
      1
      (* n (! (1- n)))))
```

One can easily see the order of execution: `1 * 2 * 3 * .... * n` and the fact that there are
`n-1` multiplications and subtractions for argument `n`.

The most important part of the Computer Science is to remember that the language is just the means of talking to computers. CS is about computers no more than Astronomy is about telescopes, and algorithms are to be executed on an abstract (Turing) machine, emulated by the actual box in front of us.

Comment: True. Perhaps the difference between "algorithm" and "actual code" is much smaller?

Comment: Funny you mentioned Turing and did not mention Lorenzo Church. Why is that? The context is FP

Comment: @AlexeiS... *Alonzo* not Lorenzo:)

Comment: @mmw aargh, thats right, ALONZO

Answer (score 8):

No, I think if you solved a problem functionally and you solved it imperatively, what you have come up with are two separate algorithms. Each is an algorithm. One is a functional algorithm and one is an imperative algorithm. There's many books about algorithms in functional programming languages.

It seems like you are getting caught up in technicalities/semantics here. If you are asked to document an algorithm to solve a problem, whoever asked you wants to know how you are solving the problem. Even if its functional, there will be series of steps to reach the solution (even with all of the lazy evaluation). If you can write the code to reach the solution, then you can write the code in pseudocode, which means you can write the code in terms of an algorithm as far as I'm concerned.

And, since it seems like you are getting very hung up on definitions here, I'll posit a question your way that proves my point. Programming languages, whether functional or imperative, ultimately are run on a machine. Right? Your computer has to be told a **step-by-step procedure** of low level instructions to run. If this statement holds true, then every high-level computer program can be described in terms of their low level instructions. Therefore, every program, whether functional or imperative, can be described by an algorithm. And if you can't seem to find a way to describe the high-level algorithm, then output the bytecode/assembly and explain your algorithm in terms of these instructions

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph of your answer.

Comment: +1 for the 3rd paragraph :) Though do programs have to run on a machine in theory? I think that you're addressing whether functions CAN be run on a machine vs MUST.

Comment: what does a program not running on a machine look like? I'm having a hard time imagining what that could possibly mean.

Comment: I was thinking of pure mathematical functions written on paper (or a blackboard!), or even the human brain "running" a program. But after re-reading my own question, your 3rd paragraph does directly address the "what I'm trying to do" part which is whether I can avoid having to document algorithms, since I dream of an industry where documents are obsolete and code is itself documentation. Sadly not.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this functional Scheme example:

```scm
(define (make-list num)
  (let loop ((x num) (acc '()))
    (if (zero? x)
        acc
        (loop (- x 1) (cons x acc)))))

(make-list 5)            ; dumb compilers might do this
(display (make-list 10)) ; force making a list (because we display it)
```

With your logic `make-list` wouldn't be considered an algorithm since it doesn't do it's calculation in steps, but is that really true?

Scheme is eager and follows computation in order. Even with lazy languages everything becomes calculations in stages until you have a value. The differences is that lazy languages does calculations in the order of dependencies and not in the order of your instructions.

The underlying machine of a functional language is a register machine so it's hard avoid your beautiful functional program to actually become assembly instructions that mutate registers and memory. Thus a functional language (or a lazy language) is just an abstraction to ease writing code with less bugs.

Comment: Beautifully stated, particularly the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Personally I like this response, but I have to give in to peer pressure in that the one I marked correct is what most would regard as the most direct answer to the question I posted even if this makes the point just as well.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat Users vote on the answers and accepting answers is just to see what answer OP found most useful. The current accepted answer is a good choice :-)